# Nuxt Dynamically Change the Enviroment Variables in Run Time Config

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

So basically my Nuxt application is being deployed on the two environments **dev** and **staging**. I am using a **base URL** to my backend server which also changes depending upon the **dev** and **staging** environment. My question is there a way to detect and change the  **base URL** in my runTimeConfig based on what kind of environment my app is running on?

Comment: For this approach, you need some devops.

Comment: I was trying to do it without any devops but I guess there is no other way. Thanks

Comment: You can pass the variable from the staging server hosting platform, and check on your Nuxt-app side, either there is a variable and you use it, either use an URL to localhost as a fallback.
So this way you will define this base URL variable wherever you want: staging, production, and review environments.

Comment: I have this issue, comment please how to solved config

Answer (score 1):

You can use environment variables to override your runtime config. Prepending a `NUXT_` to your environment variable with the same name in your config.

https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/runtime-config

For example if you have

```
runtimeConfig: {
  baseUrl: '',
}
```

When you run the application you can set the variables with

```
NUXT_BASE_URL=dev node .output/server/index.mjs
```

https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/env